# How an instance of a module created inside a class can inherit from this class (Python 3)?

Tags: class, variables, inheritance, module, parallel-processing

'I want to build a module containing **class AnimationCanvas** inside (anim.py). And I want to call this module in a separate main.py file where the data (a variable) is changing (potentially with GUI). The instance **animatedAxes** would automatically update its plot by taking data from the variables in main.py file, while the main.py code is running (a sort of parallel processes).'

'Problem: the instance of **class AnimationCanvas** from the module does not see the variables of the **class main** in the main.py file.
I know how to do it if the **class AnimationCanvas** and the **class main** are in the same file. However I want to have an animation module (separate file), which can be used anywhere, just by importing it and writing a couple of lines.'

'I can call **__init__** function of the **class AnimationCanvas** and pass the variables into it, but then it is a one-time effect, and if the variables change in **class main**, then **animatedAxes** instance will not see this change.'

'Single file which works (single.py):'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import TimedAnimation
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.size=800
        main.data=np.random.rand(self.size)

        # initialize animated graph routine
        self.animatedAxes = AnimationCanvas()  

        # run random data array
        for ii in range(20):
            main.data=np.random.rand(self.size)
            plt.pause(0.1)

class AnimationCanvas(TimedAnimation):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize random data array 
        self.data = np.random.rand(5)
        # Create animation axis and figure
        self.fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5)) 
        self.ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
        self.line1 = Line2D([], [], color='blue')
        self.ax.add_line(self.line1)

        # start animation with interval of 10 milliseconds
        TimedAnimation.__init__(self, self.fig, interval=10, blit=True)

    def new_frame_seq(self):
        return iter(range(5*5))

    def _step(self, *args):
        try:
            TimedAnimation._step(self, *args)
        except Exception as e:
            TimedAnimation._stop(self)
            pass

    def _draw_frame(self, framedata):
        # update self.data
        self.data=main.data
        # update plot with self.data
        self.line1.set_data(np.arange(len(self.data)),self.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'Two files which do not work:'

'main.py:'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from anim import AnimationCanvas

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.size=800
        self.data=np.random.rand(self.size)

        # initialize animated graph routine
        self.animatedAxes = AnimationCanvas()  

        # run random data array
        for ii in range(20):
            print(ii)
            self.data=np.random.rand(self.size)
        plt.pause(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'anim.py:'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import TimedAnimation
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np

class AnimationCanvas(TimedAnimation):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize random data array 
        self.data = np.random.rand(5)
        # Create animation axis and figure
        self.fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5)) 
        self.ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
        self.line1 = Line2D([], [], color='blue')
        self.ax.add_line(self.line1)

        # start animation with interval of 10 milliseconds
        TimedAnimation.__init__(self, self.fig, interval=10, blit=True)

    def new_frame_seq(self):
        return iter(range(5*5))

    def _step(self, *args):
        try:
            TimedAnimation._step(self, *args)
        except Exception as e:
            TimedAnimation._stop(self)
            pass

    def _draw_frame(self, framedata):
        'update self.data:'
        '????????????????'
        'update plot with self.data'
        self.line1.set_data(np.arange(len(self.data)),self.data)
```

'I tried to use **super(AnimationCanvas,self).__init__()** but it does not work.'

'In my understanding I need a direct connection between **self** of the **class main** and **self** of **class AnimationCanvas**. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.'